# Разная форма записи регулярного выражения - разный результат

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Планировал, с помощью регулярного выражения, проверить строку на длину (так надо). Но неожиданно столкнулся с тем, что разная форма записи одного и тогоже регулярного выражения, выдает разный результат.

Почему?

```js
const str = 'qwerty';
console.log(new RegExp('^.{4,15}\\b','g').test(str))
console.log(/^.{4,15}\\b/g.test(str));
```

Comment: почему одного и того же? В первом варианте `\\b` приведется к `\b`, во втором `\\b` => 2 символа `\\` и `b`. Регулярки то разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли про то, что в литерале экранирование работает по-другому:

```js
/^.{4,15}\\b/g.test('qwerty');
// => false
/^.{4,15}\b/g.test('qwerty');
// => true
```